# How to convert YUV to JPG in Java

Tags: java, image, opencv, yuv

There are arrays of bytes YUV NV21

How to do the conversion and save it to jpg file?

I use next code

```
byte[] mYUVData = YUV_420_888toNV21(planeY, planeU, planeV);
Mat mYuv = new Mat(1080 + 1080/2, 1040, CvType.CV_8UC1);
mYuv.put(0, 0, mYUVData);
Mat mRgba = new Mat();
Imgproc.cvtColor( mYuv, mRgba, Imgproc.COLOR_YUV420sp2RGBA );

// Read image as before
MatOfByte mob=new MatOfByte();
Imgcodecs.imencode(".jpg", mYuv, mob);
byte ba[]=mob.toArray();

BufferedImage bi= ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(ba));


ImageIO.write(bi, "jpg", new File("C://Users/it/Downloads/image.jpg"));
```

[But i have wrong jpg image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/diwH3.gif)

Comment: Check [this SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45926852/4725875), maybe it will help.

Comment: Thanks, but i use Java SE.
I saw that post and they use YuvImage its class only for Android (java.lang.Object
   ↳ android.graphics.YuvImage)