# How to match PreviewView aspect ratio to captured image using CameraX

Tags: android, kotlin, android-camera2, android-camerax

I have a `PreviewView`that occupies the whole screen except for the toolbar.
The preview of the camera works great, but when I capture the image, the aspect ratio is complately different.

I would like to show the image to the user after it is successfully captured so it is the same size as the `PreviewView` so I don't have to crop or stretch it.

Is it possible to change the aspect ratio so on every device it is the size of the `PreviewView` or do I have to set it to a fixed value?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can set the aspect ratio of the `Preview` and `ImageCapture` use cases while building them. If you set the same aspect ratio to both use cases, you should end up with a captured image that matches the camera preview output.

Example: Setting `Preview` and `ImageCapture`'s aspect ratios to 4:3

```
Preview preview = new Preview.Builder()
            .setTargetAspectRatio(AspectRatio.RATIO_4_3)
            .build();
ImageCapture imageCapture = new ImageCapture.Builder()
            .setTargetAspectRatio(AspectRatio.RATIO_4_3)
            .build();
```

By doing this, you'll most likely still end up with a captured image that doesn't match what `PreviewView` is displaying. Assuming you don't change the default scale type of `PreviewView`, it'll be equal to `ScaleType.FILL_CENTER`, meaning that unless the camera preview output has an aspect ratio that matches that of `PreviewView`, `PreviewView` will crop parts of the preview (the top and bottom, or the right and left sides), resulting in the captured image not matching what `PreviewView` displays. To solve this issue, you should set `PreviewView`'s aspect ratio to the same aspect ratio as the `Preview` and `ImageCapture` use cases.

Example: Setting `PreviewView`'s aspect ratio to 4:3

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.camera.view.PreviewView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="3:4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: That is a canonical answer. Please upvote!

Answer (score 4):

I was working with CameraX and faced the same issue. I followed the [excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63929571/9053942) given by [@Husayn Hakeen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4718283/husayn-hakeem). However, my app needs the previewView to match the device height width precisely. So I made some changes. In kotlin ( or java), I added

```kotlin
Preview preview = new Preview.Builder()
            .setTargetAspectRatio(AspectRatio.RATIO_16_9)
            .build();
ImageCapture imageCapture = new ImageCapture.Builder()
            .setTargetAspectRatio(AspectRatio.RATIO_16_9)
            .build();
```

And my xml has:

```xml
    <androidx.camera.view.PreviewView
      android:id="@+id/viewFinder"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
      tools:background="@color/colorLight"
      />
```

From kotlin, I measured the device actual height and width in pixel:

```kotlin
val metrics: DisplayMetrics = DisplayMetrics().also { viewFinder.display.getRealMetrics(it) }
    val deviceWidthPx = metrics.widthPixels
 val deviceHeightPx = metrics.heightPixels
```

Using these data, I used some basic coordinate geometry to draw some lines on the captured photo:
[image: demo photo]

As you can see, the yellow rectangle indicate the device preview, so this is what you see on the preview. I had a requirement to perform a center crop, that's why I drew the blue square.

After that, I cropped the preview:

```kotlin
  @JvmStatic
  fun cropPreviewBitmap(previewBitmap: Bitmap, deviceWidthPx: Int, deviceHeightPx: Int): Bitmap {

    // crop the image
    var cropHeightPx = 0f
    var cropWidthPx = 0f
    if(deviceHeightPx > deviceWidthPx) {
      cropHeightPx = 1.0f *previewBitmap.height
      cropWidthPx = 1.0f * deviceWidthPx / deviceHeightPx * cropHeightPx
    }else {
      cropWidthPx = 1.0f *previewBitmap.width
      cropHeightPx = 1.0f * deviceHeightPx / deviceWidthPx * cropWidthPx
    }

    val cx = previewBitmap.width / 2
    val cy = previewBitmap.height / 2

    val minimusPx = Math.min(cropHeightPx, cropWidthPx)
    val left2 = cx - minimusPx / 2
    val top2 = cy - minimusPx  /2

    val croppedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(previewBitmap, left2.toInt(), top2.toInt(), minimusPx.toInt(), minimusPx.toInt())
    return croppedBitmap
  }
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution is to use the useCaseGroup, where you add both preview and image capture use cases under the same group + set the same view port.

Beware that with this solution, you will need to start the camera in onCreate method when it's ready (otherwise your app will crash):

```
viewFinder.post {
    startCamera()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63902317/camerax-image-analysiss-imageproxy-size-and-previewview-size-are-not-the-same) may help for a more up to date use in Android.

In order to *standardize your resolution between PreviewView, ImageAnalysis, and ImageCapture*, **you want to 'link' all these 'cases' to a group which also incorporates 'ViewPort'**

Below was taken from the CameraX repo, link to file [here](https://github.com/android/camera-samples/blob/main/CameraXExtensions/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/cameraxextensions/viewmodel/CameraExtensionsViewModel.kt)

```
/**
 * Starts the preview stream. The camera state should be in the READY or PREVIEW_STOPPED state
 * when calling this operation.
 * This process will bind the preview and image capture uses cases to the camera provider.
 */
fun startPreview(
    lifecycleOwner: LifecycleOwner,
    previewView: PreviewView
) {

    val currentCameraUiState = _cameraUiState.value
    
    val cameraSelector = if (currentCameraUiState.extensionMode == ExtensionMode.NONE) {
        cameraLensToSelector(currentCameraUiState.cameraLens)
    } else {
        extensionsManager.getExtensionEnabledCameraSelector(
            cameraLensToSelector(currentCameraUiState.cameraLens),
            currentCameraUiState.extensionMode
        )
    }

    val useCaseGroup = UseCaseGroup.Builder()
        .setViewPort(previewView.viewPort!!)
        .addUseCase(imageCapture)
        .addUseCase(preview)
        .build()

    cameraProvider.unbindAll()

    camera = cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
        lifecycleOwner,
        cameraSelector,
        useCaseGroup
    )
    //.... code cont'd

}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/35583227)

Comment: Thanks @DavidMaze, I've updated my answer with further information based off of your feedback.