Android - How to display captured image from CameraX full size in ImageView?
I am using Kotlin CameraX, I have successfully implemented PreviewView with ratio 16:9

I successfully Captured Image using ImageCapture.takePicture(...)
imageCapture.takePicture(executor, object : ImageCapture.OnImageCapturedCallback() {
        override fun onCaptureSuccess(image: ImageProxy) {
            super.onCaptureSuccess(image)
            Log.d(BaseCameraActivity::class.java.simpleName, "onCaptureSuccess")
            image.close()
            // processImageProxyToBitmap()
            // saveBitmapImageToSingletonClass()
            // goToPreviewImageActivity()
        }
    })

When I'm in a PreviewImageActivity, I display the result of the image in ImageView, the size of the image is different when showed in a PreviewView, the ratio still same, but the ImageView doesn't want to set width & height to match parent
    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/previewImage"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    android:background="@color/red"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

THIS IS THE RESULT

THIS IS THE RESULT ONCE SCALE TYPE IS REMOVED

How can I display capturedimage full size/match parent in ImageView?

This question is already answered at below link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63925031/how-to-match-previewview-aspect-ratio-to-captured-image-using-camerax?rq=2

the ImageView still not have a match parent size @GauravBharadia

If the scale code is removed and it worked (showing full image) then there is an issue is with the parent view of ImageView. What are you using ? share it. Is it full screen?
